# Popup and Window's AllowsTransparency

Tags: wpf, popup, .net-4.5

As soon as I set `AllowsTransparency` to true in a Window and close a Popup in front of this Window, the Window is not redrawn and the popup still shows up on top of the Window.

If this Window lose focus or If I enter the "alt" key of the keyboard, the Window is redrawn and displays correctly.

To be more clear:

### Without AllowTransparency

Popup shown:

[image: Popup shown]

Popup hidden:

[image: Popup hidden]

### With AllowTransparency

Popup shown:

[image: Popup shown]

Popup hidden:

[image: Popup hidden]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Tests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="1000"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Width="1000" Height="300" Fill="Red"></Rectangle>
        <CheckBox x:Name="PopupCheckBox">
            <TextBlock Text="Show popup"/>
        </CheckBox>
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PopupCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Placement="Center">
            <Rectangle Width="500" Height="500" Fill="Green" />
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would like to know what is the cause of this behavior and how to fix/bypass it.

Thank you.

### Edit

I tried to call InvalidateVisual in the handler of the popup's Closed event but it did not change the behavior:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PopupTest.Closed += PopupTest_Closed;
}

void PopupTest_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvalidateVisual();
}
```

### Edit 2

Ok so it appear that the graphic card driver is the cause of this behavior. I updated it to the latest one and while an artifact is still shown, it behaves differently (shown area of the popup is much smaller).

Closing this thread. Thanks to all.

Comment: Have you tried to set the StaysOpen property?

Comment: @DanieleSartori I just did and it did not change the behavior

Comment: I replicated your code and i'm not having this problem. I don't know if it's related to other part of your project. The only thing i can think to solve this is to set a Trigger on the red rectangle and bind it to the IsOpen property of the popup to refill it

Comment: @DanieleSartori I ran it using framework 3.5 & 4.5. It looks like an a visual artifact. I'll look to update the graphic card driver/directX just in case

Comment: Is this your actual setup or just a simplification? Could it be something to do with your data?

Comment: @Gareth Updated the question, the cause of the issue was the graphic driver

Comment: @DanieleSartori Updated the question, the cause of the issue was the graphic driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the question's latest edit, the artifact is caused by outdated graphic card driver.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you the cause but to fix this issue use the method InvalidateVisual on your window when closing the popup.

```
window.InvalidateVisual();
```

Comment: Sadly I already tried that but it did not change anything. Updating the question

Comment: I just tried running your exact code (without InvalidateVisual) and on my machine I don't have the issue you are describing, what versions are you running?

Comment: Updated the question, the cause of the issue was the graphic driver